# Method fires up multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I call a method in my controller, but it fires up 2 times when I want to log object.name.
When I want to log whole object, it fires up 6 times. Do you know why?

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('portfolio', ['ngRoute' ]);

    app.controller('ReferenceController', function(){

        this.product = references;
        this.arrayLength = this.product.length;

        // @TODO
        this.getReferences = function(){ 

            for(var i = 0; i < this.arrayLength; i++){
                console.log(this.product[i].name);
            }

             return false;

        };

    });

    var references = [

        {
            name: "ThisIsName",
            imgUrl: "This Is Image URL",
            pageUrl: "This Is Page URL",
            tags: [
                {tag: "web"}
            ]
        }

    ];

})();
```

I call it like this

```
<div ng-controller='ReferenceController as reference'>
      {{reference.getReferences()}}
</div>
```

Comment: angular has what is called the digest cycle. it can run it as many times as needed to run the page.

Comment: @DanielA.White A. How can I prevent this looping? I am loading this JS file at the end of index.html, after page completely loads.

Comment: You want to show the reference names in your page? Currently, the names will output to a console.

Comment: @runTarm Doesn't metter where to output it. I just want to do this ONCE!

Comment: Ok, then just remove the `reference.getReferences()` call in the html. And make a call to `this.getReferences()` at the bottom of your controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot @runTarm for right answer. I dont get why I can't call this method in HTML without firing multiple times. But it works!

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Angular's two-way data-binding which uses the `$digest` loop, as it is called. (Think of it as allowing Angular to check if the value has updated.)
If you want to only run the function once, call it inside your controller.

You can [read more about the digest loop here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking specifically but

```
  for(var i = 0; i < this.arrayLength; i++){
                console.log(this.product[i].name);
            }
```

essentially means it will run through the entire array from start to end and for each value, it prints to the console once. So it prints multiple times for multiple values in the array.

Comment: I just want to print everything in `var references` once.

Comment: hmm perhaps you shouldnt have an array within an array 
tags: [{tag: "web"}]?

Comment: I dont care about object structure.
In php for example, I would do it like this
`foreach($references as $object){
    echo $object.name;
}`
and it will print name for every object in references array. Once, not multiple times.